# Retrieving Data From Firebase Database Node.js App Last Added

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app manage requests sent by users and saved on `Firebase Database`.
The `requests` listed like so:

[image]

Under `requests` I save requests sorted under user id׳s.
In my `Node.js` web server i listen to changes like so:

```
requestsRef.limitToLast(1).on('value', function(requestSnapshot) {
    var request = requestSnapshot.val();
}
```

using the  "value" to get notified when each request is added, when a new request uploaded it is uploaded under the owner "user id".
At this stage i get notified once when I start my program and also when request added (as expected) but the `request` object contain all data under `requests`, i want it to contain only the last request added.
How can I get it to work like so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve only the data on each new request added, try `child_added` instead of `value`.

Extracted from the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added):

> [..] Unlike value which returns the entire contents of the location, child_added is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data. [..]